# Multiprocessing Drops CPU to 0

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing, gcp-ai-platform-training

I have a list of data frames around 40k and I need to process each dataframe seperately.I have used multiprocessing pool.starmap with total cpus-2 as processes to process each dataframe parallely.
Process starts without any issue and suddenly cpu usage drops to 0 and runs continuosly without stopping the process
And if we manually run the process again it works sometimes.

I have tried to run in batches and with sleep time for each batch, things ran fine few times but again same issue started.

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you've found the answer to your problem.
I ran into the same issue tonight, and after a bit of research, I found out that it was because I didn't close my pool that the process just ran continuously without stopping.

Here is my code :

```
cpu_pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=WORKERS_NUMBER)
cpu_pool.starmap(func, args)
cpu_pool.close()
```

Adding the .close() allowed my program to finish running. However, I also experience drops in the CPU usage throughout the execution of the function. Still don't know why, any idea ?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33957853)